# Windows 10 on 2008 / 2008 R2 domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, windows-10

We are planning to deploy the Windows 10 in one of our site, which is running 4 domain controllers with server 2008 / R2.
Do I need to do anything /preparation in advance on the DC's in order to deploy Windows 10 without any issues.

Thanks,

Nseth

Comment: Remember 2008 is EOL in less then a year

Answer (score 0):

Works. Your domain level has to be 2003 or later for Windows 10 and if you want to use GPOs/GPPs you'll have to install them seperately.

And as additional info like @Sven says, [Server 2008 / Server 2008 R2 will be EOL soon.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?alpha=windows%20server%202008)

Comment: Lenniey, Thanks for your response.
I know 2k8 R2 extended support is coming to end currently we don't have budget to refresh the DC's or move them to Azure to extend their support. Do you think we will have some issues with the GP's or activation's with KMS on the domain?
I can't find too much information on the tech net on this as well.

Comment: You can use your [fully patched KMS service on a fully patched Server 2008R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3079821/update-that-enables-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2-kms-hosts-to) to activate Windows 10. Some newer GPOs won't natively be available, but you can install them. You are up to date on the servicepacks and updates, I hope...

Comment: Yes, SP are all update. Do you have a link for Windows 10 GPO's import ?

Comment: @Nseth https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3087759/how-to-create-and-manage-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administra

Comment: Thanks for the link.We are also planning to introduce two 2012 DC as well.Is anything I need to be careful about  ?

Comment: nope. same ad 2008, import the GPO templates and you are good to go